# If $f:X \to Y$ is a continuous function such that $f|_A =y$ then is $f|_{\bar{A}}=y$?

Tags: general-topology, continuity

If $f:X \to Y$ is a continuous function such that $f|_A =y$ then is $f|_{\bar{A}}=y$? Here $A \subset X$ and $\bar{A}$ is the closure of $A$.

This statement came across my head as I was looking at the below example.

Let $\chi_n \in C^{1,2}([0,\infty) \times \mathbb{R}^d)$ with compact support, $\chi_n |_{[0,1/2n]\times \mathbb{R}^d}=0$ and $\chi_n |_{[1/n,t]\times B(0,n)}=1$.

For the use of this cut off function, I need $\chi_n$ to be $1$ also on $[1/n,t]\times \bar{B}(0,n)$. And I think this is true by using a sequential argument, i.e., any point on the boundary of $[1/n,t]\times B(0,n)$ is a limit of a sequence of points in $[1/n,t]\times B(0,n)$, and so by continuity we get $1$ on the boundary as well. 
So I was wondering if this result holds in the more general case above. I know it holds for $T_1$ spaces, but I am curious if there's any space that such a result would not hold.

Comment: @Masacroso $A$ any subset and yes $\bar{A}$ the closure.

Comment: yes, the statement is true provided that $f$ is continuous.

Comment: So really looking at point $c$ in a T1 space.

Answer (score 3):

If $Y$ is separated, then $\{y\}\subset Y$ is closed. The inverse image of a closed set is closed, so $B=f^{-1}(\{1\})$ is closed, since $A\subset B, \bar A\subset \bar B=B$.

Otherwise, take $\mathbb{R}$ with the topology for which the open subsets are the empty subset and $\mathbb{R}$, every map $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous. The adherence of a non empty subset is $\mathbb{R}$, take $f$ to be the identity map $A=\{1\}, \bar A=\mathbb{R}, f_{\mid \{1\}}=1\neq f_{\mid\mathbb{R}}$.

Comment: Sorry I didn't make my question clear enough. I was wondering if there's any space in which the above would fail to hold.

Comment: looks like your answer is the covers all bases  and is correct. Need to get it up to #1 spot!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is true.

Since $f$ is continuous, it maps convergent sequences to convergent sequences. If $x \in \overline{A}\setminus A$ and $(x_n)$ is a sequence from $A$ converging to $x$, then $(f(x_n))$ converges to $f(x)$. But $f(x_n) = 1$ for all $n$, so we may conclude that $f(x) = 1$.

Answer (score 0):

Since an incorrect answer used sequences, I want to present some facts to dispute it and also help elucidate Tsemo Aristide's answer.

Let $X$ be a non-empty topological space with the trivial topology (i.e. with only two open sets). Let $(x_n)$ be any sequence in $X$. Then if $y$ is any point in $X$, the sequence $(x_n)$ converges to $y$. Note that EVERY sequence in $X$ has EVERY point in $X$ as a limit.

Every mapping from $X$ with the trivial topology to itself is continuous.

Since $X$ is a [first-countable space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-countable_space#Properties) (in a trivial way), we have the following (from wikipedia);

Given a subset $A$, a point $x$ lies in the closure of $A$ if and only if there exists a sequence $(x_n)$ in $A$ which converges to $x$.

This is not true for a general topological space.

The identity map on $X$ is a constant function on any singleton subset $A$ (a really trivial fact). But the closure of any subset is all of $X$, and the only way a constant function on $X$ can be the identity function is if $X$ has no more than one point in it.

Comment: a little question Mike, how you define a convergence sequence in the trivial topology? You dont need to define some metric? And I want to add: if a sequence converge to every point in the space then, how it limit can be defined? I mean, this sequence is convergent?

Comment: If $U$ is any open set containing $y$, then there is a $N$ so that when $n$ is > N $x_n$ is in $U$. Any $N$ works since $U$ = $X$. Any constant sequence approaches every point in $X$.

Comment: @Masacroso The closure of any point is all of $X$. Also see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_sequence#Topological_spaces for general def of a sequential limit.